# What to do if the arrows are too far to the left?

Tags: equipment, technique, archery

When shooting (recurve, rh) my arrows are far left of the sight. I can't adjust it any further left because it's at the end of the thread for the pin and it's the longest pin I could find.

What could be wrong with the setup that would cause such a big drift to the left?

Comment: Right-hand (your holding or drawing hand?). Left of the sight (the arrow tip during your draw, or where it lands once you've shot?).

Comment: Yes, RH shooting - all arrows group to the left and i can't get them any further to the right via the sight pin.

Comment: Normally the line from your eye through your sight to your target should be almost parallel to your arrow. If you have to max-out the length of your sight-pin, then it seems that your arrow is at a very large angle. Maybe your hand is in front of your face instead of under your chin, or when you release the string you are moving the arrow away from your chin. It could also be the arrow-rest on the bow, that is pushing the arrow to the left. Post a picture/video of you shooting and I can say more. Views from your chest-side and the drawing-arm side would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at you shoot or your setup, assuming that your recurve is properly set up and tuned, I would say that you are 'plucking' the string and pulling your hand out away from your face, with proper form, the string should leave the finger tab because the fingers are so relaxed they can no longer hold the weight and then your fingers should come back to the back of your neck. If this is done everytime; then it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to tighten your push button. If that does not work, try adjusting your tiller, and if that does not work, you can try increasing the brace height. If that does not work, increase the number of strands in your string. If that does not work, go for weaker arrow shafts.