# What to do if recurve arrows are far to the right?

Tags: technique, archery

I am shooting a recurve bow, and my arrow group is to the right.

My problem is that my sight pin is already over as far right as it goes, and if I move it any further I won't be able to see it anymore.

Is there anything else I can adjust to bring my group over to the left?

Comment: I don't know anything about archery, but judging just from the title, this seems related: [What to do if the arrows are too far to the left?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-to-do-if-the-arrows-are-too-far-to-the-left). (BTW this question was shown also in related links on the right.)

Comment: It seems to me that you would have different things to do in order to bring your arrows more to the left, than the main answer at least says for that question.  Some adjustments in archery (in fact, most, other than simply aiming intentionally off center) are unidirectional.  This should not be closed as duplicate, at least without some feedback from someone expert in the field.

Comment: This is definitely a dupe of https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2875/what-to-do-if-the-arrows-are-too-far-to-the-left - it's the same problem with the same cause (usually a form issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured it out. The problem was that my sight picture was about three inches off.